# A box contains 6 white balls and 5 black balls. Find the number of ways 4 balls can be drawn from the box if two must be white?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> A box contains $6$ white balls and $5$ black balls. Find the number of ways $4$ balls can be drawn from the box if two must be white?

1st Approach I thought was

Selecting two white balls from the bag $^6C_2$ and then selecting the other two from the remaining balls in the bag $^9C_2$, so the answer should be $^6C_2\cdot{^9}C_2$.

2nd Approach was

Making the cases for $2$ white balls then $3$ white balls and then $4$ white balls and then adding up all the cases to get the answer.

The problem is the answer from both these approaches is different, so I want to know which one is correct and why? and which one is wrong and why? because only one can be correct.

Comment: You seem to be assuming the white balls are distinct.  As I read the problem they are identical.  In that case there are $2^4=16$ orders you can draw four balls, $11$ of which have at least two white.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first approach is incorrect.  It assumes the white balls are distinct, but it overcounts the cases of more than two white balls.  You would count the case of $W1,W2,W3,B1$ three times, once with the first two white balls $W1, W2$, once with $W1,W3$ and once with $W2,W3$.  In each case the third white ball is one of the two remaining balls.